# Number of bootstrap replications for computing BCa in "boot"

Tags: r, statistics

I am using "boot" package in R to compute BCa confidence. However, I got an error message like "Error in bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L= L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o,  :  estimated adjustment 'a' is NA". I could find BCa with 2000 replications for a dataset with N=2000, but had the above error message when using 1000 or 1500 replications. Does anyone know what the error message means? Is it related with the number of bootstrap replications? Many thanks for any advice or suggestions!